# angular keycloak bearer token causing cors issue/provisonal headers are shown

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I am using the keycloak-angular(10.0.1) keycloak-js(18.0.0) npm
Angular(13.0.3)

I have 2 apps that are clients in my local keycloak. One being the angular app the other being a java spring rest API.

I am able to log in through keycloak and generate a token from the angular app. I can then use the token in postman to successfully hit the java server to grab the resources needed.

The issue I am having is when I try to directly hir the java server with the angular app instead of postman.

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
  console.log('keycloak init');
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        realm: 'dev',
        clientId: 'frontend'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        checkLoginIframe: true,
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: false,
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    }).finally(() => {
      console.log("finally!");
      scriptsService.load('env').then(() => {
        console.log("Loaded env variables:", window["env"])
      }).catch(error =>
        console.warn("Unable to load script: ", error)
      ).finally(() => {
    });
  });
}


{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true
},
```

The code above is in my app.module.ts and works perfectly I am able to log in to keycloak and redirect back to the angular app.

on the landing page after login a request is done to get all available teams.

```
this.teamsService.fetchTeams().subscribe(value => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (value.length != 0) {
        
      }
      this.teams = value;
      this.selectedTeam = this.activeTeamService.getActiveTeam();
    });
```

```
fetchTeams(filter?: any): Observable<Team[]> {
    return this.getList(this.TEAMS, filter, this.teamAdapter);
};
```

```
protected getList(path, params, adapter): Observable<any> {
    let options = {
      params: params
    }
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase + path, options)
      .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data ? data.map(item => adapter.adapt(item)) : data))
      .pipe(catchError(err => this.error(err)));
  };
```

This is all working as expected because it does not return the teams because the bearer token is set to false.

The issue is When I set `enableBearerInterceptor: true,` in the init.

The network tab shows this request.

[image]

The token shows in the request but the java app is not getting it.
headers received from the java app.

```
host = localhost:7770
connection = keep-alive
pragma = no-cache
cache-control = no-cache
accept = */*
access-control-request-method = GET
access-control-request-headers = access-control-allow-origin,authorization
origin = http://localhost:4200
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-mode = cors
sec-fetch-site = same-site
sec-fetch-dest = empty
referer = http://localhost:4200/
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate, br
accept-language = en-US,en;q=0.9
```

I have tried everything but I cannot seems to add the auth token without causing the issues above. Let me know if you need any more information.

Edit:

The endpoint I am trying to hit is a GET
localhost:7770/teams

Comment: Is your angular app sending cors headers…?

Comment: yes I have it set to * just to try and get it working

Comment: Yeah. Not a good idea really. It can make your cors issues worse. Thise headers need to be set by the server..

Comment: The server looked like it has these when I took a look. This seems correct because it is trying to do a get request.
access-control-request-method = GET
access-control-request-headers = access-control-allow-origin,authorization

Answer (score 0):

Some have reported missing dependancies with [similar issues](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/180#issuecomment-572554974).

app.module

```
providers: [
    {
      // Keycloak initialization
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializerKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
],
```

rest.module

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
],
```

Comment: Hmm interesting let me give that a try thanks

Comment: I tried adding the intercept like they showed, but it seems to give the same issue when I try to change the headers at all.